# How to set the 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' statement with SQLitePCL

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, uwp

I have been using [SQLitePCL](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/) (currently ver 3.8.7.2), and now decided to experiment with Delete and Update Cascade by turning on the Foreign Key constraint. I understand this feature is disabled by default and according to [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable), the constraint must be enabled separately for **each database connection**.

The connection string only takes a database path (for SQLitePCL anyway) and doesn't allow more flexible composite connection string of the form `data source=d:\foo\bar\mySqlite.db;foreign keys=ON`. If I have to turn on the constaint for **every connection** as shown below, how to turn on the constraint?

I was expecting the `ISQLiteStatement` API to provide some means of injecting the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` statement into my **connection statement** but see no obvious [Intellisense] method or property to achieve this. Exploring the SQLiteConnection API is not even a starter as turning on the foreign key constraint is *per connection* anyway.

Note: `DeleteItemByIdQuery()` and `BindIdToDeleteItemByIdQuery()` methods below return SQL Query strings and details omitted for brevity.

```
using (ISQLiteStatement statement = new SQLiteConnection("d:\foo\bar\mySqlite.db").Prepare(DeleteItemByIdQuery()))
{
    BindIdToDeleteItemByIdQuery(statement, id);
    SQLiteResult result = statement.Step();
}
```

Am I overlooking something simple, or is this impossible? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

Keep the `SQLiteConnection` as an outer `using` block and execute a sequence of PRAGMA and the main statement within it. Funny I thought I tried the same before and didn't get the result I'm getting now -- other mistakes may have been at work then.

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"d:\foo\bar\mySqlite.db"))
{
    // First turn ON the FK constraint

    using (var statement = conn.Prepare(@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"))
    {
        SQLiteResult result = statement.Step();
    }

    // Then Delete item that will Cascade deletion in referencing table(s)

    using (var statement = conn.Prepare(SqlDeleteItemById()))
    {
        SqlBindIdToDeleteItemById(statement, id);
        SQLiteResult result = statement.Step();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that it is very inefficient to re-open the database for every query.

Answer (score 0):

The PRAGMA statement is a normal SQL statement; just execute it.

To reduce the amount of typing, you can write a helper function for creating a connection and configuring it.

Comment: I know the PRAGMA is a normal SQL; the question is how to execute within a single connection. I tried the PRAGMA and the main statement sequentially within the `using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection` block but didn't work. That made me assume that the PRAGMA may have to be part of a single `ISQLiteStatement  statement` but ... Looks like the most basic thing that should be obvious but surprised        that couldn't figure it out despite the fact that I have used SQLitePCL with most of it features (and decided to move on to relational integrity maintenance with FK constraint but got stuck!).