# Why can't turn off foreign key constraint through entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'd like to turn off the foreign key constraint check in an SQLite database through entity framework (just to migrate a table content to another one with modified columns). The command I use for this is `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;` (also tried `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;`). The command works fine if I use it through an SQLite Studio, it turns off the the check and I can drop the table.

The problem comes when I try to execute it from the code (C#, WPF, Entity Framework):

`var result = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;");`

The result is always `-1` and I can't drop the table because the foreign key constraint fails. I also tried to execute it in a new context, and also in a transaction with and also without the `drop` query, but it does not turns off the constraint check. What I miss?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800240/34092

Comment: Thanks, using direct `SqlLiteConnection` it works! It seems that through the Entity framework for some reason it does not turns off the constraint check.